# Can I use global variables in React Native to store user information?

Tags: react-native, global-variables

I have an application that has hundreds of screens. I usually pass the variables from parent to child between the components with props. I find it very uncomfortable to pass the array with the user information hundreds of times.

I am testing the global variables of react native. Does it have any danger to use a global variable to save user information and modify it within the components?

I have searched for documentation and nothing is said. I know it's not correct in react, but it works wonders for me.

Any recommendation?

Comment: How about local storage?

Comment: I have used it in several applications, but I do not like it because of the nuisance in the code and sometimes it is not immediate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that global variable is a constant or it's value doesn't effect rendering of components then you are good to use it as global variable or async storage.

But if it's value is changing and affecting the rendering of component then I highly recommend you to store that value as state and to make it global you can either use
 1) Context api (https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)
 2) Or Redux

Comment: I understand that you say it by limiting the shouldcomponentupdate? ... with global I imagine that it is not possible.